# How to store JS variable in a database

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP and since several days I try to store a java script variable with the help of ajax (jQuery) in a mysql database.

I'm using the following code to do this:

```
 <!-- document javascripts -->    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#saveForm').submit(function(){
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: formUrl,
                data: formData,
                success: function(data,textStatus,xhr){
                        alert(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr,textStatus,error){
                        alert(textStatus);
                }
            }); 
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I click on the submit button, Ajax will post the whole sourcode of my webpage. =(

What I need is a function to store a java script variable to my database but without reloading the page.

I am grateful for any help =)

Comment: The page is reloading as well?

Comment: No, page is not reloading. This works fine. Even the variable 'formData' is filled with proper data. But ajax still shows the whole source code =(

Answer (score 1):

You told jQuery to serialise a form element. That is, convert the form element to a text string. In other words, you are telling it to get the form's HTML code and send that to your server.

I don't know (or want to know) what the correct way of sending a form's data by AJAX is, but I do know that you need to actually do something like access the form's fields to get their values.

Answer (score 1):

My js is a bit rusty but try changing:

```
var formData = $(this).serialize();
```

To:

```
var formData = $('#saveForm').serialize();
```

Or:

```
var formData = $('#saveForm').val().serialize();
```

That's assuming you want to serialize and store the html of the whole form.

To pull just a value from the form (I don't think you need serialize) try:

```
var formData = $('#saveForm #someInputName').val();
```

Of course changing someInputName to whatever the actual name of the field you want to save is.

Comment: Hi, thanks everybody for replying =) Now I'm using the following statement: `var formData = $('#saveForm').val();` When I print out this variable it works fine. But the value of the data variable from the ajax block is still the whole page =(

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in data parameter.. `$('#saveForm').serialize();`
should be ok

Comment: She's getting the url from the action attribute of the form, obviously it's not wrong because as stated: "Ajax will post the whole sourcode of my webpage". The problem is what it's posting, not where it's going.